# Check whether common elements between two list are in same order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example there are three lists:

```
list_1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
list_2 = ["a","x","b","y","c"]
list_3 = ["b","a","c"]
```

```
common_elements = ["a","b","c"]
```

Now my requirement is to find out that if the lists have common elements, whether they appear in same order.

Here for example in list_1 the order of common elements are a,b,c & in list_2 also the common elements appear in the same order a,b,c as in list_1

But in list_3 the common elements are not in the same order as list_1.

How can we say whether the common elements are in the same order.

Comment: Are the common elements given in advance, as in your `common_elements` list, or are you supposed to "detect" them from a pair of lists?

Comment: @jdehesa detect them based on the lists.

Comment: you can write some code to look through the lists find common elements then check the ordering

Comment: Make sets from your lists, use set intersection to find common elements, filter the lists to only contain elements from that set, compare the list for equality.

Comment: @deceze Yeah after rereading I saw what you meant and already deleted it. But really you can avoid that part by simply using a tuple (elem, idx) in the first place for the sets (that is after all the identity we're interested in)

Comment: @Voo Not sure how a tuple would help here, unless you use a completely different approach in the first place.

Comment: @apoorva Is the number of lists fixed, i.e. are there always 3 lists, or is that variable? The end result is just supposed to be a single boolean whether *all* lists have common elements in the same order, or do you need some more nuanced result?

Comment: @deceze I think what apoorva wants is a general solution.

Comment: @deceze You want all the elements that have the same value (say 'a') and are at the same index in their respective list (say position 1). Hence the set of the first list would be `{ ('a',1), ('b',2),.. }`. The intersection of these sets gives you the correct answer.

Comment: @Voo No, not at the same index. Just *in the same order* relative to each other.

Comment: @deceze I really need my coffee before trying to read, yup you're right :-)

Comment: @deceze basically i need to construct a final_list of all these sublists(the no. of lists and no. of elements in each list can vary).
I start by doing final_list.extend(list_1) without verifying any order as its an empty list to start with. 
when i process the second list list_2, i want to make sure that the elements in list_2 are in the same order as elements already present in final_list, if not raise an error and rest of the elements are just added into the final_list.Hope this made some sense :D

Answer (score 3):

It's slightly unclear whether you need an intersection of all three lists together, or just any two of them. Here's an illustration of a simple approach for any two lists:

```
>>> list_1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
... list_2 = ["a","x","b","y","c"]
>>> common = set(list_1) & set(list_2)
{'a', 'c', 'b'}
>>> l1 = [v for v in list_1 if v in common]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l2 = [v for v in list_2 if v in common]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l1 == l2
True
```

Comment: instead of `l2`-- `it = iter(list_2); all(v in it for v in l1)` ?

Comment: That's clever too, and is certainly a good approach if you have very long lists and want to save memory. For tiny lists like this, I prefer the simplicity of a simple `==`.

Comment: Yah it saves memory and short-circuits too, but agree, not that readable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply iterating one of the lists and searching for the common elements in the second one, but starting the search from where you found the previous element. For example, something like this:

```py
def common_in_order(lst1, lst2):
    # Find common elements
    common = set(lst1)
    common.intersection_update(lst2)
    # Index of the last element found in lst2
    prev_idx = 0
    # Iterate elements of lst1
    for elem in lst1:
        # If it is a common element
        if elem in common:
            try:
                # Look for the element from the previous index onwards
                prev_idx = lst2.index(elem, prev_idx)
            except ValueError:
                # If the element could not be found they are not in the same order
                return False
    # If there were no errors then elements were in the same order
    return True

# Test
list_1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
list_2 = ["a","x","b","y","c"]
list_3 = ["b","a","c"]
print(common_in_order(list_1, list_2))
# True
print(common_in_order(list_1, list_3))
# False
print(common_in_order(list_2, list_3))
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
list_1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
list_2 = ["a","x","b","y","c"]
list_3 = ["b","a","c"]

common_elements = ["a","b","c"]

for ix, l in enumerate([list_1, list_2, list_3],1):
    correct_order = True
    if set(common_elements).issubset(set(l)):
        idx = l.index(common_elements[0])
        for i in common_elements[1:]:
            if l.index(i) < idx:
                correct_order = False
                break
        if correct_order: print(f'list {ix} is in correct order')
        else: print(f'list {ix} does not have correct order')
    else:
        print(f'list {ix} does not have all common elements')
```

Output:

```
list 1 is in correct order
list 2 is in correct order
list 3 does not have correct order
```